# Checking if vertices of polygon are in clockwise or anti-clockwise direction in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, topology

Is there a simple way to calculate a field in QGIS indicating if the vertices of each polygon feature in a layer are in **clockwise** or **anti-clockwise** direction?

For simplicity, lets assume the layer has multiple polygon features, with a single geometry per feature (no multifeatures/multipolygons), and without donuts or other complications.

I have found related questions, but none of them give an answer to my question.

These ones are ESRI specific:

- [Order of polygon vertices in general GIS: clockwise or counterclockwise](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119150/order-of-polygon-vertices-in-general-gis-clockwise-or-counterclockwise)
- [Polygon creation (Clockwise rotation or not)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48747/polygon-creation-clockwise-rotation-or-not)

This one resolves the problem from a math point of view, but not applied to QGIS

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order

The same algorithm is implemented in a shapely function - see links provided by Andreas Muller:

- http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.algorithms.html
- https://web.archive.org/web/20080209143651/http://www.cgafaq.info/wiki/Polygon_Area

Comment: If you can implement a little script in Python, The Shapely-Module has a function called `signed_area`: http://toblerity.org/shapely/shapely.algorithms.html. Polygons the must be read into a Python-Data-Structure and the first ring must be extracted. But anyway: all outer rings of polygons in a shapefile have the same orientation: clockwise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, the shapefile standard indicates polygons must always go clockwise.  However QGIS accepts polygons in any direction when the provider is not a shapefile.   https://issues.qgis.org/issues/6283 . I am interested in a simple way calculate them in a field for those layers.  The algorithm you suggest with shapely is the same one explained in the last link of my question.  Yes, I may end up programming it but I am interested in checking first if there is a simpler solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses the Advanced Python field calculator in QGIS 2.18 [described here](https://anitagraser.com/2013/04/20/advanced-python-field-calculator/) and the function signed_area (i copied it from [shapely source code](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/algorithms/cga.py))

In the dialog we choose the *Input layer* first and a *Result field name* (somename) and *Field type' (Float). In the *Global expression* field we insert code of a python function called signed_area:

```
def signed_area(pr):
    """Return the signed area enclosed by a ring using the linear time
algorithm at http://www.cgafaq.info/wiki/Polygon_Area. A value >= 0
indicates a counter-clockwise oriented ring."""
    xs, ys = map(list, zip(*pr))
    xs.append(xs[1])
    ys.append(ys[1])
    return sum(xs[i]*(ys[i+1]-ys[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(pr)))/2.0
```

And in the field called *Formula* we write:

```
value = signed_area($geom.asPolygon()[0])
```

Because asPolygon returns a list like object, we make sure to access the outer ring by using index 0 on that list. The result can be saved to a temporary layer and shows up in QGIS after calculation. An disadvantage may be, the a totally new layer is created, instead of just a new field is created.

Comment: That is the kind of answer I was looking for, thanks.  I made a small modification to the code so it delivers a text field with "clockwise" and "anti-clockwise" labels directly; you can see it in my post below.

Comment: @Andreas Müller shouldn't it be `xs.append(sx[0])` instead of 1? Because I suppose they're trying to close the ring by adding the first point to the list.

Comment: No, it's because the formula needs always an `i+1` and at the last repetition of the list comprehension the second point is needed. Search for shoelace formula to get a visual explanation.

Answer (score 3):

For anybody looking for the same answer, below is how I implemented the code based on Andreas Muller's answer.  It delivers a text field with a "clockwise" or "anti-clockwise" label for each polygon.

- In QGIS, go the the Processing Toolbox > Advanced Python field calculator
- Select your input layer
- Field type = String
- Length = 30 (or choose whatever fits you)
- Global expression:

(paste this)

```
def signed_area(pr2):
     """Return the signed area enclosed by a ring using the linear time
     algorithm at http://www.cgafaq.info/wiki/Polygon_Area. A value >= 0
     indicates a counter-clockwise oriented ring."""
     xs, ys = map(list, zip(*pr2))
     xs.append(xs[1])
     ys.append(ys[1])
     return sum(xs[i]*(ys[i+1]-ys[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(pr2)))/2.0

def rotation_dir(pr):
     signedarea = signed_area(pr)
     if signedarea > 0:
         return "anti-clockwise"
     elif signedarea < 0:
         return "clockwise"
     else:
         return "UNKNOWN"
```

- value: `rotation_dir($geom.asPolygon()[0])`

I verified this works well in QGIS for a vector layer (memory provider, not a shapefile) with polygons rotating in multiple directions (clockwise and anti-clockwise).

Comment: There is another interpretation of the return value. If signed_area returns 0, then the polygon ring is not closed.

Comment: The label in that case will be `UNKNOWN`.  If I ever get that result it will lead me to have a look at the polygon and see what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is to determine whether a polygon has its points set CW or CCW, shapely objects have a property for that:

```
import shapely
polygon = shapely.geometry.Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)]) 
polygon.exterior.is_ccw # False
polygon = shapely.geometry.Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)])
polygon.exterior.is_ccw # True
```